# JS Parsing the error stack on the server side using sourcemaps

Tags: javascript, bundle

I have a JS SPA (Single page application) with React.
Of course, I use webpack, babel and build my project.
The prod version has minimized JS code and I deploy it.
But the problem that minimized version has a terrible error stack.
I'm able to store sourcemaps on my server, but I have a problem:
How to parse minimized error stack using sourcemaps?

I found the lib (retrace) which allow to do it, but it takes current js file from the prod server (I mean that it go to your site and takes bundle.min.js). And after that, it parses it using sourcemaps which I can store on the server.

This way does not work when you try to parse old error stacks when the versions had changed.

So the questions: how to parse errors stacktrace on the server side using sourcemaps?